# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, attributeerror

Help me please with my code.

```
relation_tables = char_soup.find('ul', class_='subNav').find_all('li')
like_page_url = url + relation_tables[2].find('a').get('href')  # Get like page's url
dislike_page_url = url + relation_tables[3].find('a').get('href')  # Get dislike page's url
like_r = requests.get(like_page_url)  # Get source of page with users who liked/disliked
dislike_r = requests.get(dislike_page_url)
like_soup = BeautifulSoup(like_r.text, 'html.parser')
dislike_soup = BeautifulSoup(dislike_r.text, 'html.parser')
like_pages = int(like_soup.find('ul', class_='nav').find_all('li')[13].text)
dislike_pages = int(dislike_soup.find('ul', class_='nav').find_all('li')[13].text)
n = like_soup.find('table', class_='pure-table striped').find_all('tr')  # WORKS
for i in range(0, like_pages):
    like_users_trs = like_soup.find('table', class_='pure-table striped').find_all('tr') # DON'T
    curr_character_like_names.extend([f'{url}{tr.find("a").text}' for tr in like_users_trs])  # Get
                                                                                                    # all users names
    like_page_url = url + like_soup.find('li', class_='next').find('a').get('href')  # and extend them to a list
    like_r = requests.get(like_page_url)  # Then find 'next' button and get next page's url
    like_soup = BeautifulSoup(like_r.text, 'html.parser')  # Get source of the next page
```

This code should take list with users names from page with users who liked character and who disliked(2 different pages). Problem is that one of 2 lines that do same thing don't work:
`n = like_soup.find('table', class_='pure-table striped').find_all('tr')`(that line is just for test)
That one is outside the loop and works good, but equal line inside the loop(`like_users_trs = like_soup.find('table', class_='pure-table striped').find_all('tr')`) throw error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sekki/Documents/Pycharm/anime_planetDB/main.py", line 131, in <module>
    like_users_trs = like_soup.find('table', class_='pure-table striped').find_all('tr') # DON'T
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Additional info:

- like_page_url = https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/armin-arlelt/loves
- dislike_page_url = https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/armin-arlelt/hates

Comment: For whatever reason "like_soup.find('table', class_='pure-table striped')" yields nothing, as it's stating by it receiving a Nonetype. Nonetype does indeed not have find_all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are over complicating this a bit. Looking at the patterns, the names start to repeat once you got past the last page. So just do a `while True` loop until that happens.

Secondly, let `pandas` parse that table for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


def get_date(url):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[0])
    page = 1
    continueLoop = True
    while continueLoop == True:
        url_page = f'{url}?page={page}'
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
        response = requests.get(url_page, headers=headers).text
        temp_df = pd.read_html(response)[0]
        
        if list(temp_df[0])[0] not in list(df[0]):
            print(f'Collected Page: {page}')
            df = df.append(temp_df)
            page+=1
        else:
            continueLoop = False
            
    return df


dfLoves = get_date('https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/armin-arlelt/loves')
dfHates = get_date('https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/armin-arlelt/hates')
```

**Output:**

```
print(dfLoves)
                  0
0         atsumuboo
1         Ken0brien
2           Kabooom
3          xsleepyn
4    camoteconpapas
..              ...
21        SonSoneca
22  SayaSpringfield
23          Kurasan
24     HikaruTenshi
0     silvertail123

[15026 rows x 1 columns]

print(dfHates)
                 0
0           selvnq
1   LiveLaughLuffy
2      SixxTheGoat
3        IceWolfTO
4         Sam234io
..             ...
11     phoenix5793
12          Tyrano
13      SimplyTosh
14      KrystaChan
15     SHADOWORZA0

[2591 rows x 1 columns]
```